# CSS transition not working after element is appended

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have encountered an issue with CSS transitions and before I try something else, I want to understand what the problem is.

There are 3 boxes in a container and a "next" button. The goal is for the next box top appear on top and to fade in when the "next" button is pressed. The box is positioned on top by appending it to the container, so that it is added as the last element and thus visible on top, and should fade in through css transition.

The problem is that the css transition does not seem to work after the box was appended.
The css transition works well if tested on a box element that is not appended.

[Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/z435s/13/), code below:

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="box red"></div>
    <div class="box blue"></div>
    <div class="box green"></div>
</div>

<div id="next">Next</div>
```

JS:

```
var container = $(".container");

// Save the current list order
var list = container.children(".box");
// The current index
var current = 0;

// Put the first on top
container.append(list[0]);

function next() {
    // Figure out what is the index of the next box
    if (current + 1 < list.length) current++;
    else current = 0;

    // Save it in a variable
    var target = $(list[current]);

    // Put it on top
    container.append(target);

    // Hide it and then fade it in
    target.css("opacity", 0).css("transition", "opacity 1000ms ease-out").css("opacity", 1);

    // The fading in is not working
}

$("#next").click(next);
```

**Update**:

A basic solution to this problem was to call offset() on the target after setting the opacity to 0 and before setting the transition css:

```
target.css("opacity", 0);
target.offset();
target.css("transition", "opacity 1000ms ease-out").css("opacity", 1);
```

[**Updated** version of the above fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/z435s/14/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "list" variable is a jQuery object, but the elements you pull out of it as "target" are **not** jQuery objects - they're the DOM nodes. Thus your calls to ".css()" are failing (which is reported in the error console for me).

Once you've fixed that, then the next thing is the issue of how the browser deals with a sequence of CSS updates.  It's not clear to me what exactly I'm seeing (from Firefox 18 on Linux), but I *think* the basic issue is that because no layout reflow is done between the changes, the net effect is that the styles are "collapsed" so that there's no net change.

In [this update to the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fUNw2/1/) I took a different approach. I put the transition rules in the "box" class, and then added a "prefade" class:

```
.prefade {
  transition-duration: 0;
  opacity: 0;
}
```

Then, instead of messing with the element style, I add "prefade" before appending, and then trigger a layout update by asking for the element's offset.  Then I can remove the "prefade" class, and the box fades in.

```
target.addClass('prefade');
// Put it on top
container.append(target);

var p = target.offset();

target.removeClass('prefade');
```

I don't know whether that's the "right" way to do things. *edit* — to make it work in Chrome, the "transition" properties need to be repeated with the `-webkit-` prefix.

Comment: you're right, but in my tests fixing that doesn't fix the problem

Comment: @Alnitak yes I agree; it's got something to do with how updates to "transition-duration" are meshing with the direct updates to the opacity.  I don't fully "get" the semantics of that stuff :(

Comment: hence why my answer doesn't use transitions ;-)

Comment: @Pointy, sorry, this is just something I missed to include in the demo I created, I will fix that momentarily. And like Alnitak mentioned, the problem with the transition still exists.

Comment: @Pointy, the solution that you proposed works both in Chrome and Firefox. It is more of a hack to the way the browsers handle the code and very helpful in understanding what is happening as this was my main scope, to understand what is occurring and why. Thank you.

Comment: @jsgroove well thank you for the question. As I said, I barely understand the design rationale for these things.  It certainly seems strange to have to "trick" the browser like that.

Comment: @Pointy I was looking through your code and testing things out and stumbled over a very simple solution to the initial code of just adding one line. Just call offset() in between setting the opacity of the target to 0 and setting the transition css. I detailed this together with the modified fiddle in an update to the original post, above. Regards.

Comment: @jsgroove yes that makes sense - the call to `offset()` forces a "reflow", and that has to take into account any and all pending CSS changes.  Cool!  I'm glad you've made progress because I was mostly just guessing :-)

Answer (score 2):

Is there any particular reason to use CSS transitions, when you could use jQuery fades instead and have your code work on browsers that don't support CSS transitions?

```
var $container = $(".container");

function next() {
    var $next = $container.children().first();
    $next.hide().appendTo($container).fadeIn();
}

$("#next").click(next);
```

Note that you can avoid a lot of the state you're maintaining merely by taking the first element from the container and moving it to the back - the DOM maintains your state for you!

See http://jsfiddle.net/alnitak/w6y3B/

Comment: Yes, I need to use CSS transitions. It is a larger project that I have and this is only a basic demo of the problem that I have encountered.

Comment: @jsgroove that's a shame.  As Pointy suggests, this looks like an issue with setting the opacity twice in a row with no delay - I expect the latter one cancels the first transition.

Comment: @Alnitak I may have gotten it to work; the approach I took doesn't seem like it can really be the "right" thing to do.

Comment: Well I'm not surprised really. In Firefox, I noticed that if I did a `setTimeout()` to delay removing the class, it had to be for at least 100ms.  It seems pretty flaky.  It may be that for something like this, the CSS animation feature would work better, but I don't understand that yet either!

Comment: It looks like Chrome just needs `-webkit-` on the various transition properties.

Comment: Commenting in 2020, most browsers support transitions now. The reason to not to use it is performance and smoothness of CSS transitions